# Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime

Tags: php, date

I am using the following script to pull the calendar info out of the mysql database and display it on the page. I am trying to re format the date from the standard Mysql date format , but when retrieving it from the database am getting the following error :

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\managecalendar.php on line 24

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\managecalendar.php on line 24

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\managecalendar.php on line 24

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\managecalendar.php on line 24
```

The Database (as you can see the dates are stored correctly):
[image]

The script :

```
<?php
     $sql2 = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `calendar`
    SQL;
    if(!$result2 = $db->query($sql2)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    echo '<table class="admintable"> <thead>';
    echo '<tr><th>Client Names</th><th>Email</th><th>Tel</th><th>Wedding Date</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Price</th><th>Location</th><th>Other Info</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr></thead>';
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $weddingdate = $row2['weddingdate'];
    $formattedweddingdate = date_format($weddingdate, 'd-m-Y');
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row2['name'].'</td><td>'.$row2['email'].'</td><td>'.$row2['tel'].'</td><td style="min-width:70px;">'.$formattedweddingdate.'</td><td style="min-width:70px;">'.$row2['datecreated'].'</td><td>'.$row2['starttime'].'</td><td>'.$row2['endtime'].'</td><td>&pound;'.$row2['price'].'</td><td>'.$row2['location'].'</td><td style="min-width:400px;">'.$row2['otherinfo'].'</td><td><a href="managecalendar.php?&key='.$key.'&editwedding='.$row2['id'].'">Edit</a></td><td><a href="calenderdelete.php?&key='.$key.'&delwedding='.$row2['id'].'">Delete</a></td></tr>';}
    echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: date($weddingdate, 'd-m-Y');

Comment: @Pramod Your parameters are the wrong way round...

Comment: I think people panic when they see warning and don't read it. Warning says that function expects instance of `DateTime` but you've passed `string` so your variable `$weddingdate` contains date string, so all you need is to create object of `DateTime` (e.g. `date_format(new DateTime($weddingdate), $desiredFormat)`)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Best way is use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object to convert your date.

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $weddingdate);
$formattedweddingdate = $myDateTime->format('d-m-Y');
```

**Note:** It will support for PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 only.

Comment: Thanks, thats got it now ! :-)

Comment: I don't know what this was closed as "too local"—it certainly solved my problem.

Comment: This answer worked where several other answers across the internet gave me errors, the key was telling DateTime the format of the date string I had

Answer (score 31):

You need to pass DateTime object to this func.
See manual:
[php](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php)

```
string date_format ( DateTime $object , string $format )
```

You can try using:

```
date_format (new DateTime($time), 'd-m-Y');
```

Or you can also use:

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 15):

Why don't you try it like this:

```
$Weddingdate = new DateTime($row2['weddingdate']);
$formattedweddingdate = date_format($Weddingdate, 'd-m-Y');
```

Or you can also just do it like :

```
$Weddingdate = new DateTime($row2['weddingdate']);
echo $Weddingdate->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 4):

This may help

```
$formattedweddingdate =date('d-m-Y',strtotime($weddingdate));
```

Comment: Please provide some context or details to answer, as to why this solves the problem so it may help others.

Comment: The strtotime() function parses an English textual datetime into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) and the date() function formats it.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$start_date = date_create($_POST['start_date']);
$start_date = date_format($start_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried sean662's 3rd solution and worked with now() function stored in an INSERT sql an then it's value in the date_create() function. After that the variable is then passed through the date_format() function and you can have the date order that you like.