# Date is not converting in the desired format

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

i am using PHPExcel to import a data to the database. All is going well but i am having a problem in data column. I have two types if excel sheet. One having date column as a general format it did not give any error.

But in the second excel sheet there there was error after some debugging i came to know that in excel there is formatting of the cell in the date format.

This is the code which i try to run

```
$formatted_date = $this->worksheet->getCell($this->date . $row)->getFormattedValue();
        $dat = date_format($formatted_date, "Y/m/d");
```

i was converting it into date and from this i got this error

```
date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

then i try to make it a date format object from this by creating a date

```
$formatted_date = date_create($this->worksheet->getCell($this->date . $row)->getFormattedValue());
        $dat = date_format($formatted_date, "Y/m/d");
```

but then it is giving the error of boolean

```
date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given
```

any help would be much appreciated if this is the phpexcel pr the php problem.?

Comment: Checked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567999/5447994?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is a format that DateTime cannot recognise, then you should probably use [date_create_from_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) instead, and tell it what format you are using.

Alternatively, rather than using

```
$formatted_date = $this->worksheet->getCell($this->date . $row)->getFormattedValue();
```

use

```
$dateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject(
    $this->worksheet->getCell($this->date . $row)->getValue()
);
```

and you can then use all the appropriate PHP [DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) methods such as [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to do whatever you want with the value.

Comment: hello @Mark Baker sir! the reason why i am not using is, i have to specify the format of the date.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? It looks like you're trying to get a date string formatted as `"Y/m/d"`.... so what can't you use my alternative suggestion?

Comment: sorry my previous comment was not complete yes i am trying your alternative solution.

Comment: So you create the $dateTimeObject as I've shown, and then `$dat = $dateTimeObject->format("Y/m/d");`

Comment: sir i tried and it worked but it is giving the output like "1900/01/01"

Comment: no problem sorry i did not see the getValue and was using formatted value instead. Thankx for your help.