# date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given (View: /home/vagrant/code/blog/resources/views/singlePost.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I cant find whats wrong with my code. I have tried looking at the whole code but I can't put my finger on it. It would be really helpful if someone pointed out my mistake. It is saying that something is wrong with the date but I cant see what I typed wrong.

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('{{asset('assets/img/post-bg.jpg')}}')">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="post-heading">
              <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
              <span class="meta">Posted by
                <a href="#">{{$post->user->name}}</a>
                on {{date_format($post->created_at,'F d,Y')}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Post Content -->
    <article>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            {!!nl2br($post->content)!!}
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="comments">
  <hr>
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <hr>
  @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
  <p>{{$comment->content}} <br>
  <p><small>by {{$comment->user->name}}, on {{date_format($comment->created_at,'F d,Y')}}</small></p>
  <hr>
  @endforeach

@if(Auth::check())
<form action="{{route('newComment')}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Comment..." name="comment" id="" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="post" value="{{$post->id}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class ="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Make Comment</button>
</div>
</form>
@endif

</div>
</article>
    @endsection


comments.blade.php code
```

Comment: please add code not image here ? Actually high power camera can't see  properly this shared image.

Comment: i added the code above sorry

Comment: share any sample data of `$post->created_at` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: date\_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567854/warning-date-format-expects-parameter-1-to-be-datetime)

Answer (score 2):

Error show you must have `DateTime` object

```
  $created_at = new DateTime("2018-02-01");
  echo date_format($created_at,'F d,Y');
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/995941)

If you have just date like `2018-02-01` Then you can use simple `date()` function

```
$created_at = "2018-02-01";
echo date('F d,Y',strtotime($created_at));
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/995947)

You can also do it by

```
echo (new DateTime("2018-02-01"))->format('F d,Y');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/995954)

Comment: but the dates are not manually inputted they are connected to a db

Comment: use `(new DateTime($comment->created_at))->format('F d,Y');`

Comment: or  `date('F d,Y',strtotime($comment->created_at));`

Comment: @C2486 `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040436/laravel-how-can-i-validate-reset-password-table-token-and-request-token` help me for this.!!

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is old, but this thread came up whilst I was searching for a solution and mine was to do this when reading from my database:

```
$evdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['when']);
```

And then this to display the date in page without error:

```
<?php echo($evdate->format("H:i d/m/y")) ?>
```

Hope this helps whoever else comes across this, I was using `date_format` which, although worked and displayed on screen correctly, was throwing an error which I wanted to squash from my logs. (and presumably having it done right will be better than a bodge that seems to work).